# How to Keep ISEModuleBrowserAddon from Disappearing in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Every time I close and re-start Powershell ISE the Module Browser disappears and I have to re-import the module. Is this just poor intended behavior? Sort of a nuisance to have to Import-Module ISEModuleBrowserAddon each time I use the ISE...

Powershell Version 5.1:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  502
```

Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Consider using Visual Studio Code IDE for Powershell.  It's less error prone than ISE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and follow [`Import-Module` reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1):

> `Import-Module` imports a module **only into the current session**. To
>   import the module into all sessions, add an `Import-Module` command to
>   your Windows **PowerShell profile**. For more information about profiles,
>   see [about_Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1).

Further reading: [How to Use Profiles in Windows PowerShell ISE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-use-profiles-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had not read that reference before asking, much appreciated.