Auto Load PowerShell Modules (PWSH) To Windows PowerShell
Below List of Modules was installed on PowerShell 7 (a.k.a PWSH) in my PC:
AzureAD
ManageBootStick
PoshFunctions
PowerShellAI
PowerShellAI.Functions
PowerShellAIAssistant
PSWriteColor
SMBIOS
SysInfo

When I run a script in Windows PowerShell (a.k.a PowerShell 5.1),
If one of these modules not yet installed in powershell 5,
How to make it's command available for PS5, without installing it ?
Because was installed in PS7

I make an example:
module PSWriteColor was installed in PS7, not yet installed in PS5.
PS7 Console:
(gcm -m PSWriteColor).Name
 Write-Color -c Green 'Test'

Output:
Write-Colour
Write-Color
Test

PS5 Console:
(gcm -m PSWriteColor).Name
Write-Color -c Green 'Test'

Output:
# Null
Write-Color : The term 'Write-Color' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,....

How to Auto Load PSWriteColor module to PS5, without installing it ? Because was installed in PWSH module
So, i just install the module once and it can be used for both

Update
I tried to check $env:PSModulePath with command $env:PSModulePath.Split(';')
PS7 Output:
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules
c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

PS5 Output:
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

It's look different. So, what do I have to do?

Unclear : What is available without installation?

Available in PS7 but not available in PS5.

perhaps like import-module from PS7 to PS5

Some modules are limited to a specific PS version. Also, the way to load modules "automatically" in PowerShell is via your Profile. You place any modules you want to load into the Profile and these will be imported each time you start a PS session. I'd guess these modules are listed in your PS7 profile already.

But, modules MUST be installed before they can be imported/loaded. Can you please EDIT your post to make it more clear?

was edited? clear? sorry for my english

Most PS5 modules can work in PS7, but the other way is not truly documented. If PS7 cannot find an installed module in its paths, it will then look in the PS5 paths afterwards and load it from there if present, if the -UseWindowsPowerShell parameter was specified. If you have a module in PS7 that doesn't exist in PS5, it's unknown whether it can be transferred. You may modify PSModulePath of PS5 to include PS7, but it's unknown if it will work. (Just a guess.)

Okay. I'll try to edit $env:PSModulePath

Add to your comment @harrymc for me to be notified.

-@harrymc Oh. Sorry. I forget it

So you have to verify that the modules are compatible with PS 5.1 to start. Then you can use the profile as mentioned, or wrap conditional logic to verify that module for a command you want to run is there, and then if not use a combination of conditional If along with try{}catch{} blocks to install if not exist within the scripts, etc. I have used this strategy a lot since I share my script with other IT team members near the top as a prerequisite type check along with comments, etc. Mainly M365 scripts in my case, but same strategy should work, just gotta work out the conditional checks.

This question and its answer has all the info necessary regarding PS Profiles. While it references the ISE, the information is essentially the same: https://superuser.com/questions/1251518/how-to-keep-isemodulebrowseraddon-from-disappearing-in-powershell-ise/1278799#1278799

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle  Can you share the script as an example? so I can edit it according to my needs.

@Mr.Key7 Here is a screen shot of a simple example: https://imgur.com/2P47zpy but for your specific modules, you need to test to ensure you wrap the conditionals to work the way they are supposed to work BOTH with the modules and without the modules. I have more examples but connected from elsewhere to VPN to grab this quick one, I'm not really working today but this should give you an idea of how to wrap the logic to start, might take some trial and error but should suffice. The PS Profile might be better though, I do things the hard way sometimes.

@music2myear It seems like the easiest way is to modify the $Profile, rather than modifying the $Env:PSModulePath

Well yes, because that's the way PS intends for you to load modules into your sessions. Modifying the Module path will break things, importing existing modules into your session is how you bring them in to be used during your work.
